# Rationalising a fraction with a surd

Tags: irrational-numbers, rationalising-denominator

The given fraction is: $$\frac{2}{1+\sqrt5}$$

Can someone explain to me how to rationalise this (*in steps - GCSE Level*)?

*My only idea is to mutliply the top and bottom by $1+\sqrt5$ ??*

TIA.

Comment: Should be $1-\sqrt{5}$ instead.

Comment: @Mathaholic Huh, Multiply by $1 - \sqrt5$ ?

Comment: Yes, try it yourself, and $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2-b^2$.

Comment: @peterwhy Surly if I multiply the top and the bottom by $1 - \sqrt5$ I'll end up with what I started with? http://goo.gl/UofHtM

Comment: Did you read the Alternative forms in your WolframAlpha link?

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, but I have no clue how they get from the original fraction to those, that's what I kinda need to understand.

Comment: So the hint to simplify the denominator is the identity $(a+b)(a-b) \equiv a^2-b^2$. For more, there is an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac 2 {1+ \sqrt 5} = \frac {2 (1-\sqrt 5)}{(1+\sqrt 5)(1 - \sqrt 5)} = \frac{2(1-\sqrt 5)}{1 - 5} = \frac{2(1-\sqrt 5)}{-4} = \frac{-(1-\sqrt 5)}{2} = \frac{\sqrt 5 - 1} 2.
$$

Comment: $$= \frac1 2(\sqrt5 - 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

When you see one of $a+\sqrt{b}$ or $a-\sqrt{b}$ in the denominator, you need to supply the other one (on top and bottom) so that both forms appear together in the denominator.

The reason is to take advantage of the fact that
$$(a+\sqrt{b})(a-\sqrt{b}) = a^2-a\sqrt{b}+a\sqrt{b}-(\sqrt{b})^2 = a^2-b$$
(assuming $b$ is a positive number).

Comment: Using this, I got as far as $\frac{2-2\sqrt5}{1-5}$

How do I get any further?

Comment: Subtract $5$ from $1$ in the denominator. Once you’ve done that, mltiply top and bottom by $-1$. Once you’ve done that, divide top and bottom by $2$.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks so much! (I am stupid :/)

Comment: Not stupid! Just unpracticed.